# Unable to set a TextBox text owned by MainWindow from another class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am trying to set a TextBox value text owned by MainWindow (WPF Window) from another class in the same namespace, but nothing happens. I've gone through many suggestions and answers to similar questions with no avail. What puzzles me is that MainWindow's SetText receives the text as it is being displayed in Visual Studio console, but doesn't have any effect on the actual textbox. The 'ConsoleLog' textbox has the default XAML values.

So my MainWindow is similar to this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }    

    public string SetText
    {
        get { return ConsoleLog.Text; }
        set {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            ConsoleLog.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Test()
    {
        var mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.SetText = "Please display something!";
    }
}
```

I tried with several other methods such as:

```
((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ConsoleLog.Text = "Please display something!";
```

but nothing works so far without any error messages.

I'm fairly new to WPF C# and I'm sure it is something very obvious I'm missing, but it drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF project Default project start up MainWindow by configuring its App.xaml file, not by app.xml.cs. if you want to get access to MainWindow , you should initiate MainWindow manually by following code

```
public App()
{
    var mw = new MainWindow();
    mw.SetText = "Please display something!";
    mw.ShowDialog();
}
```

and remove the following line from App.xaml

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
```

if you want to get started with WPF application and make a good app,I recommend you to see some basic tutorial, and try to learn MVVM (or MVC in web) programming methodology.

Comment: Ahh thank you! That did the trick. I missed the part with the StartupUri in App.xaml. For reference to others, I had to use `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                mw.SetText = "Test";
            });` in some parts of my code to avoid calling thread errors.

Comment: If you use MVVM methodology , you will decrease use of calling from other thread. I forgot thread interferes. My bad.